# Sort all query results in 2 categories

Tags: mysql, sql

I have transaction data in a MYSQL table.  One of the fields is name of the supplier.  However in a number of records the supplier is not specified (literally 'UNSPECIFIED').

So the data looks like :

```
ID     Date          Supplier            ---
1       1 Nov 2013    Green supplier
2       3 Nov 2013    Red supplier
3      15 Nov 2013    UNSPECIFIED
4       2 Dec 2013    UNSPECIFIED
5       6 Nov 2013    Blue supplier
6      20 Nov 2013    UNSPECIFIED
```

x 100,000 etc

I can sum and group each month using SUM(IF(date_format (date, '%b, %Y')= 'Nov, 2013', 1,0)
etc to get something like -

```
                Nov 2013   Dec 2013  
UNSPECIFIED        1        2
Green supplier     1        0
Red supplier       1        0
Blue supplier      0        1     etc
```

However I want a simplified version that breaks results down into (1) is UNSPECIFIED and (2) Everything else totalled.  So the results look like -

```
                Nov 2013   Dec 2013  
 UNSPECIFIED        1        2
'Not UNSPECIFIED'   2        1     etc
```

While still retaining the sum per month format.
I am sure this should be simple, but I can't think of how.  Can anyone advise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would add conditional logic to the `group by` in your query:

```
select (case when supplier = 'UNSPECIFIED' then 'UNSPECIFIED' else 'SPECIFIED' end),
       . . . 
from . . .
group by (case when supplier = 'UNSPECIFIED' then 'UNSPECIFIED' else 'SPECIFIED' end);
```

In MySQL, you don't actually have to repeat the logic in the `group by`:

```
group by 1
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  I didnt know about linking the case to group by.  Works great.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `case` statement as

```
case when supplier='UNSPECIFIED' then 'UNSPECIFIED' else 'Not UNSPECIFIED' end column_name
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I used the answer above by Gordon